# General (Set Builder) definition for a relation composed with itself n times

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, relations, predicate-logic, function-and-relation-composition

### Questions

1. What does the set builder notation for $S\circ R$ look like? I'm having the most trouble knowing when there is too much information or not enough information on either side of the 'such that'.
   $$S\circ R=\{ a\in A\land c\in C\land\exists b\in B\mid (a,b)\in R\land (b,c)\in S\}$$
   $$S\circ R=\{(a,c)\mid(\exists b\in B)\rightarrow((a,b)\in R\land(b,c)\in S)\}$$
2. A relation $R_1$ is difined on the set of integers such that $$R_1=\{(a,b)\mid a>b,\:\:\:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$ How would I write the set builder notation for the recursive composite of $R^n_1$ in terms of $a,b$ and $n$?
3. As a part of question #2; In order for me to understand why the set builder definition looks the way it does I need to understand how to find $R^n_1$ for the relation $R_1$. What is a mathematical process, not an intuitive guess and check solution, that I can employ to see what is happening with respect to the given relation?

---

### Current Understandings

- [Set-builder notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) is a mathematical notation to describe a set in general form. It's short hand to cut down long worded explanations. A set is usually expressed using curly brackets : $\{\cdots\}$. The set builder notation is formulated by {(a variable)("such that")(logical predicate)}

> ***ex***: The set containing all positive real numbers:
>
> Denoted in *set builder* notation as:
>   $$\{x\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\land x>0\}$$

- A [binary relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) on a set $A$ (of $n$ elements) is a group including pairs of elements from the set $A$. Namely, a relation $R$ on a set $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$ containing $2^{n^2}$ relations.

> ***ex***: The relation "less than" is the set containing pairs of numbers where the first number is less than the second number.
>
> Denoted in *set builder* notation as:
>   $$R=\{(a,b)\mid a<b\}$$

- When you take the [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_functions) of multiple relations you join the set mapping of one relation to another (and so on). Let $R$ be a relation from set $A$ to set $B$ and $S$ a relation from $B$ to a set $C$.
  $$R\subseteq A\times B\text{ and }S\subseteq B\times C$$
  The *composite* of $R$ and $S$ (denoted by $S\circ R$) is the relation consisting of ordered pairs $(a,c)$, where $a\in A,c\in C$, and for which there exists an element $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in S$.

**(QUESTION 1)**

> ***ex***: $R$ is a relation on two sets such that $R=\{(1,1),(1,4),(2,3),(3,1),(3,4)\}$ and $S$ is a relation on two sets such that $S\{(1,0),(2,0),(3,1),(3,2),(4,1)\}$
>
> $$S\circ R=\{(1,0),(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(3,0),(3,1)\}$$

- Continue to let $R$ be a relation on a set $A$. When composing the parent relation with itself, the powers $R^n, n=1,2,3,\dotsc,$ are defined recessively by $R^1=R$ and $R^{n+1}=R^n\circ R$. This shows that $R^2=R\circ R, R^3=R^2\circ R, and so on.$

**(QUESTION 2,3)**